# Cargar select al seleccionar fecha

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

Tengo que cargar un select con diferentes datos, según 
la fecha que se elija, y no sé cómo lograr esto.

Lo único que se me ocurrió fue ocupar `onchange` en el `input` donde se muestra
la hora, pero no funciona. Leí por ahí que `onchange` no funciona muy bien
si el `input` no tiene el "foco". Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, saludos.

Esta es la vista de los campos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar el boton del calendario se abre esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego seleccionamos la fecha y queda así, y en este punto necesito cargar un select al momento de escoger una fecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu pregunta está demasiado desarrollada. se puede resumir en: cargar combobox tras seleccionar fecha.

Comment: Hola!, agrega el codigo que utilizas, como obtienes los datos? de una base de datos? de un select en bruto?

Comment: Deberías agregar tu código

Comment: el calendario está realizado con algún plug-in en concreto? Si es así tal vez ese plug-in tenga una función para realizar la tuya propia al seleccionar una fecha

Comment: ¿Has probado oninput en lugar de onchange?

Comment: Eso tienes que hacerlo con jquery, no sabría exactamente como ya que no tengo mucha idea de jquery, pero yo hice algo parecido una vez y tuve que usar jquery

Comment: en un campo de texto  como es tu caso `onchange` lanza el evento cuando se pierde el foco. Si quieres que se lance en el momento que algo cambia dentro del campo deberías usar `oninput`

Comment: Si la logica de lo que quieres lograr esta en el onchange de tu input, simplemente despues de seleccionar la fecha debes lanzar/gatillar por codigo el evento onchage de tu input. en jquery sería $('tuinput').trigger('change');

Comment: Si estás agregando la escucha del evento desde javascript, el evento es 'change', y no 'onchange'.

Answer (score 1):

Sin tu código es un poco complicado responder, no obstante, en base a las capturas de pantalla, parece que estás trabajando en dos ventanas de navegador. Lo recomendable sería que esa ventana que lanzas como popup fuese una capa flotante (un , por ejemplo) en el mismo documento, para poder comunicarte con el campo de formulario sin problemas.

Así funciona, por ejemplo el [plugin datepicker de jquery ui](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo con **[jQuery](https://www.jquery.com)** (la forma mas fácil de trabajar) de como cambiar un `select` al cambiar el campo fecha:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 $("#fecha").on("change",function () {
  $("#opciones").html("\
   <option>opcion a</option>\
   <option>opcion b</option>\
   <option>opcion c</option>");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fecha" type="date">
<select id="opciones">
<option>opcion 1</option>
<option>opcion 2</option>
<option>opcion 3</option>
</select>
```